# Запись значения после срабатывания функции.

Tags: javascript, методы

[image: скриншот]

Куда записывается значение count после того как внешняя функция срабатывает и возвращает внутреннюю? А также появляется ли у переменно sayHi объект LexicalEnvironment c локальными переменными, может быть данная переменная записывается туда?

Comment: Здравствуйте! Прошу вас, в следующий раз вставляйте код не изображением. а в само сообщение, чтобы можно было скопировать код. Я сам недавно изучал "область видимости", попробую вам ответить. После записи функции в переменную, она(функция в переменной) сохраняет свою "область видимости"(на момент создания) и ссылается на нее своим свойством `[[Scope]]` и через это свойство, может брать значение `count` и перезаписывать его.

Answer (score 1):

Значение переменной count находится внутри функции. В этом просто убедиться, если, например, продолжать вызывать sayHi - счетчик (тот самый count будет увеличиваться).

Это работает так, потому что count находится в области видимости функции и живет там в течение всего времени существования функции ([Чтиво](https://learn.javascript.ru/closures) по теме. Там же и про LexicalEnvironment).

```js
var sayHi = (function() {
  var count = 0;
  
  return function() {
    count++;
    
    console.log('Hello ' + count);
  }
})();
```

```html
<button onclick='sayHi()'>Old hello</button>
```

Самым простым способом узнать значение count в любой момент - вынести переменную в глобальную область видимости (очень очень очень плохой вариант)

Правильное направление, это реализация интерфейса, getter'ов и setter'ов.

```js
var sayHiNew = (function () {
  var count = 0;

  var interface = {};
  
  interface.run = function() {
    count++;
    console.log('New Hello ' + count);
  };
  
  interface.changeCounter = function(newNumber) {
    count = newNumber;
  };

  interface.getCounter = function() {
    console.log(count);
    return count;
  }

  return interface;
})();
```

```html
<button onclick='sayHiNew.run()'>New hello</button>
<button onclick='sayHiNew.changeCounter(10)'>Change count to 10</button>
<button onclick='sayHiNew.getCounter()'>Get current 'count' value</button>
```

В идеале же, по моему мнению, лучше это дело держать объектами:

```js
var sayHiObj = function() {
  this.count = 0;
  
  this.run = function() {
    this.count++;
    console.log('Hello ' + this.count);
  }
  
  this.getCount = function() {
    console.log(this.count);
    return this.count;
  }
};

var sayHi = new sayHiObj();
```

```html
<button onclick='sayHi.run()'>Say hi</button>
<button onclick='sayHi.getCount()'>Get 'count'</button>
```

Полезная [ссылочка](http://www.adequatelygood.com/JavaScript-Module-Pattern-In-Depth.html).

Про объекты одной ссылкой не обойдешься, поэтому там уже сами найдете